# WSO2 ESB, how to handle timeout in Iterator/Aggregate

Tags: timeout, wso2-esb

I'm working from a couple of months on WSO2 Esb and I need at moment to split an incoming message using an Iterator mediator, send each part to an end point and collect the answers using an aggregate mediator.
Something like this:

```
  <iterate expression="//element" id="ELEMENTS">
    <target>
      <sequence>
        [send to endpoint using element data]
      </sequence>
    </target>
  </iterate>
  <property name="root" scope="default">
    <root xmlns=""/>
  </property>
  <aggregate id="ELEMENTS">
    <completeCondition timeout="12">
      <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
    </completeCondition>
    <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="root" expression="//resultelement">
        [rest of the flow]
    </onComplete>
  </aggregate>
```

It works properly but, as you can see, I defined a time out on aggregator so message in timeout won't be "aggregated" and will be "redirected" to fault sequence. Generally speaking any message sent to fault sequence will "miss" the aggregator so the question is: there is any way to aggregate in a single message the answers and the errors?

The "plan B" is based on a single error message created in the fault sequence and sent back using respond mediator, it works but in case of multiple errors I notice a null pointer exception in esb's logs, I assume due to multiple processes trying to use respond mediator.

Thank you

**EDIT**:

I'm new to ESB so probably I had the wrong idea so I'll try to explain my case with an example.
I'm trying to create a REST API that will receive a payload like this:

```
{
    "items" : [
        "ID_ITEM_1",
        "ID_ITEM_2",
        "ID_ITEM_3"
    ]
}
```

*API config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="AAA/report" name="order-request" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <resource methods="POST" protocol="http">
    <inSequence>

      <iterate expression="//items" id="ITEMS">
        <target>
          <sequence>
            <property expression="json-eval($.items)" name="item"/>
            <call-template description="Get status" target="gov:/calls/GetItemStatusTemplate.xml">
              <with-param name="itemId" value="{get-property('item')}"/>
            </call-template>

            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>
                {
                    "item" : "$1",
                    "status" : "$2"
                }
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg expression="get-property('item')"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.status"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>

          </sequence>
        </target>
      </iterate>
      <property name="report" scope="default">
        <report xmlns=""/>
      </property>
      <aggregate id="ITEMS">
        <completeCondition timeout="12">
          <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="report" expression="//jsonObject">
          <respond/>
        </onComplete>
      </aggregate>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence>
      <log level="full">
        <property name="FAULT_SEQUENCE" value="IN"/>
      </log>
      <respond/>
    </faultSequence>
  </resource>
</api>
```

The GetItemStatusTemplate will use the itemId to perform a call to an endpoint like this:

```
<call>
  <endpoint>
    <address trace="disable" uri="http://something">
      <timeout>
        <duration>10000</duration>
        <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
      </timeout>
      <suspendOnFailure>
        <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
        <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
        <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
        <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
      </markForSuspension>
    </address>
  </endpoint>
</call>
```

Let's assume the answer from the endpoint is something like:

```
{
    "status" : "OK"
}
```

So the API's answer to the original request (in case of no timeouts) should be something like this:

```
{
    "report" : [
        {
            "item" : "ID_ITEM_1",
            "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
            "item" : "ID_ITEM_2",
            "status" : "NOT VALID"
        },
        {
            "item" : "ID_ITEM_3",
            "status" : "OK"
        }
    ]

}
```

in case ITEM_3's request goes in timeout the answer will be:

```
{
    "report" : [
        {
            "item" : "ID_ITEM_1",
            "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
            "item" : "ID_ITEM_2",
            "status" : "NOT VALID"
        }
    ]

}
```

but my idea is to create something similar to this:

```
{
    "report" : [
        {
            "item" : "ID_ITEM_1",
            "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
            "item" : "ID_ITEM_2",
            "status" : "NOT VALID"
        },
        {
            "item" : "ID_ITEM_3",
            "status" : "request timeout"
        }
    ]

}
```

Or a way to notice the client with the error on ITEM_3

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you are asking to handle "timeout" in aggregate mediator.

- Timeout used in completion condition to handle aggregate process. If responses not going to meet timeout period, it will stop the aggregate process.

There will be a warning as follows:

```
WARN - Aggregate Aggregate Mediator Time out occured.
```

Other than that, there will be no redirection to fault sequence.

In your question, you ask to aggregate responses with errors. If you can please explain more on your issue.

- But I have to explain that, responses vs errors are handling using different mechanisms. And timeout of aggregate doesn't redirect to fault sequence.

Note: As I saw in your sample, you should put aggregate mediator into out sequence rather than adding into insequence.

Hope this will help to get your answers. If you need more clarifications, comment on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dilshani. Your note is right I'm using only the insequence because, inside the iterator, I'm using an existing sequence template that actually contains a call not a send, hope is not a big deal because I can't change it in a send. About the timeout you're again right, is not the aggregator's timeout to send the message in fault sequence but the timeout defined into endpoint definition:              <timeout>
            <duration>10000</duration>
            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
          </timeout>

Comment: by the way the only alternative available for <responseAction> is 'drop',  that for sure won't help me. My goal is create a message that is a kind of report of all the messages call made inside the iterator so should contain both correct answers and messages representing wich one was in timeout.

Comment: You can add whole synapse configuration to analyze further. Rather than that, I still didn't get your requirement. Do you wanna create a message including error messages? You can refer WSO2 Documentations regarding exact flow of data. As I feel, there is a misunderstanding about the requirement with ESB functionalities.

Comment: I edit my answer adding a simple example that should help to understand my needs